# How to convert dutch dates into date/time format in MsAccess

Tags: import, ms-access-2007

I have TSV files that contains columns with *Dutch* formatted text fields in dd-MM-YYYY format, like 22-OKT-2004 and 05-MRT-2004. I want to import the file to Access.

The date columns should be imported as date/time objects. However, the above mentioned months (MRT, MEI, OKT) are not recognized, probably because they differ from the corresponding english abbreviations. How should I use the import wizard to still import these objects?

(Strangely, if I import the columns as text columns, and convert them later via table design, it does work. But I don't like this option because some of the TSV files are so big that converting after importing (instead of during the import) gives an error: Microsoft office can't change the data type; there is not enough disk space or memory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue using the "French (Canada)" regional setting in Windows. For a tab-delimited file

```
ID  DonorID Amount  DateString
1   1       8       01-janv-2013
2   1       2       01-févr-2013
3   1       3       01-mars-2013
4   1       4       01-avr-2013
5   1       5       01-mai-2013
7   2       5       01-juin-2013
8   2       6       01-juil-2013
13  2       4       01-août-2013
14  2       7       01-sept-2013
15  2       9       01-oct-2013
16  2       6       01-nov-2013
17  2       7       01-déc-2013
```

if I tried to import the date column directly to a `Date/Time` field in Access I would get conversion errors for every month except "oct" and "nov" (where the French abbreviation matches the English one). However, I could import the date field as `Text`, and then if I run the query

```sql
SELECT ID, DonorID, Amount, CDate([DateString]) AS DateValue
FROM importedData;
```

the [DateValue] column shows the correct dates. So, you could conceivably import the dates as `Text` and then

1. use the above query directly, or
2. change it into a make-table query (`SELECT ... INTO NewTableName FROM ...`) to re-write the dates as actual date values.